# Why is the hex value of a period in a DNS request not 0x2E, and why does it change?

Tags: networking, dns, udp

Looking at a DNS request in wireshark for `www.google.com` and the hex for it is `03 77 77 77 06 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65 03 63 6f 6d 00`

Little confused why the first period is `03` (and why it's there), the second is `06`, and the last is `03`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The DNS protocol layer is defined in [RFC 1035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt). To cite from "3.1. Name space definitions":

> Domain names in messages are expressed in terms of a sequence of labels.
>   Each label is represented as a **one octet length** field **followed by that
>   number of octets**.  Since every domain name ends with the null label of
>   the root, a domain name is terminated by a length byte of zero.

Thus `www.google.com` is encoded in the DNS packet as:

```
03 77 77 77                  length 3, "www"
06 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65         length 6, "google"
03 63 6f 6d                  length 3, "com"
00                           length 0 (end of label)
```

Comment: Ah! It's the length! I should have been able to notice that. Thank you.